Journey builder - can I send to multiple distribution lists?
We are looking at moving from Email Studio to Journey Builder so we can use the A/B testing.
I currently capture multiple audiences by using automated Outlook distribution lists that I have uploaded into Salesforce, so we can access granular data on each audience for analytical reasons.
I have found that I cannot select more than one Distribution List when building in Journey Builder - is there a way around this?
Thank you.

A/B testing feature is in Email Studio not in Journey Builder.
You cannot select multiple data sources in a journey. However, you can combine these data sources into 1 data extension, then use this DE for the journey.
I list some steps here for your reference:

Create a data extension
Build a SQL query activity to combine data into the target DE above
Create an automation in Automation studio and run the SQL query activity above
Use the target DE in journey builder as the entry source


Additionally you could then add Path Optimizer in your journey for A/B testing.
